# Chocolatey can't install (Unable to connect to the remote server)

Tags: chocolatey

I have installed Chocolatey on my Windows 10 machine and then I have setup an internal Chocolatey registry on a internal Nexus instance.

I have setup my Nexus instance as proxy for default official Chocolatey registry and I'm able to search packages but not able to install them...

Log file content when searching:

```
2019-05-03 09:37:32,955 7708 [DEBUG] - Searching for package information
2019-05-03 09:37:32,961 7708 [DEBUG] - Running list with the following filter = 'maven'
2019-05-03 09:37:32,961 7708 [DEBUG] - --- Start of List ---
2019-05-03 09:37:33,128 7708 [DEBUG] - Attempting to gather credentials for 'https://xxxxxxx/nexus/repository/chocolatey-packages/'
2019-05-03 09:37:33,132 7708 [DEBUG] - Using saved credentials
2019-05-03 09:37:33,508 7708 [INFO ] - maven 3.5.2
2019-05-03 09:37:33,512 7708 [DEBUG] - --- End of List ---
2019-05-03 09:37:33,514 7708 [WARN ] - 1 packages found.
2019-05-03 09:37:33,516 7708 [WARN ] -
```

This is what's in the log file when I try to "choco install maven":

```
2019-05-03 09:11:53,985 11996 [INFO ] - Installing the following packages:
2019-05-03 09:11:53,989 11996 [INFO ] - maven
2019-05-03 09:11:53,992 11996 [INFO ] - By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
2019-05-03 09:11:54,083 11996 [DEBUG] - Using 'https://xxxxx/nexus/repository/chocolatey-packages/'.
2019-05-03 09:11:54,225 11996 [DEBUG] - Attempting to gather credentials for 'https://xxxxx/nexus/repository/chocolatey-packages/'
2019-05-03 09:11:54,235 11996 [DEBUG] - Using passed in credentials
2019-05-03 09:11:54,415 11996 [DEBUG] - - Supports prereleases? 'True'.
2019-05-03 09:11:54,419 11996 [DEBUG] - - Is ServiceBased? 'True'.
2019-05-03 09:11:54,537 11996 [DEBUG] - Package 'maven' found on source 'https://xxxxxx/nexus/repository/chocolatey-packages/'
2019-05-03 09:12:15,583 11996 [ERROR] - maven not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to connect to the remote server
2019-05-03 09:12:15,589 11996 [INFO ] - maven package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
2019-05-03 09:12:15,593 11996 [DEBUG] - No package information as package is null.
2019-05-03 09:12:15,626 11996 [DEBUG] - No package information to save as package is null.
2019-05-03 09:12:15,628 11996 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2019-05-03 09:12:15,630 11996 [ERROR] - The install of maven was NOT successful.
2019-05-03 09:12:15,634 11996 [ERROR] - maven not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to connect to the remote server
2019-05-03 09:12:15,644 11996 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
```

Comment: Are you able to download if you bypass Nexus Repository Manager?

Comment: At the moment we only use a hosted repository in Nexus. We haven't setup a proxy to the "official" chocolatey repository as we only should use Chocolatey for "internal packages" (licensed stuff). For all other we use another tool.

Comment: I will try to setup the proxy - and see if I can download an official chocolatey package...

Comment: @joedragons: I have tried removing the Nexus server as "source" and instead using the official chocolatey repo: https://chocolatey.org/api/v2 and then I'm able to both search and install for example a tomcat package. I have also tried setting up https://chocolatey.org/api/v2 as a nuget proxy in Nexus and put it into the Nexus nuget group together with my "hosted/internal" Chocolatey. Then I'm still able to search my internal packages and also the official ones. But I can't install them. Same error: An error occurred during installation:
 Unable to connect to the remote server.

Comment: Strange that I'm able to search the packages but I'm not able to install them....

Comment: Agree.  I was trying to make sure it was NXRM.  When you say "the log file" do you mean nexus.log?  Or is there a chocolately log file?  Sorry I'm not really familiar with Chocolatey.

Comment: It is the Chocolatey log I have attached - I will try to look into the nexus.log